# How do I submit a custom bst style file to CTAN?

Tags: bibtex, ctan

I have modified the plainnat.bst natbib style file in order to submit to the journal Arctic. It works fine, and I figured it might be useful to someone else. Is there a way to submit custom bst files to the official CTAN repository so that someone in the future submitting to Arctic can just download the bst and use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just go to

http://www.ctan.org/upload

and follow the steps outlined.